# If lock in C# has like RAII behavior?

Tags: c#, .net

It is a little bit confusing. In C# for multithread managing we have mutex and we have lock and in addition I found such lock RAII implementation

```
        public class ReaderWriterLockSlim_ScopedLockRead : IDisposable
        {
            ReaderWriterLockSlim m_myLock;

            public ReaderWriterLockSlim_ScopedLockRead(ReaderWriterLockSlim myLock)
            {
                m_myLock = myLock;
                m_myLock.EnterReadLock();
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                m_myLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }

        public class ReaderWriterLockSlim_ScopedLockWrite : IDisposable
        {
            ReaderWriterLockSlim m_myLock;

            public ReaderWriterLockSlim_ScopedLockWrite(ReaderWriterLockSlim myLock)
            {
                m_myLock = myLock;
                m_myLock.EnterWriteLock();
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                m_myLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to understand the difference between them, as for me mutex is a first multithreading managing implementation you need to call `mutex.lock()` and then don't forget to call `mutex.release()` it is usually not so suitable to call `mutex.release()` because you can get an error at the middle of execution, so here we have `lock(obj){}` as far as I see it is kind of RAII object with the same behavior but if you get error at the middle under the hood it will call `mutex.release()` and all nice.

But what about the last custom implementaion that I posted? It looks like the same with `lock(obj){}`, just with a difference that we have `read and write` behavior, like in write state it is possible that a few threads get accesses to method and with read state just one by one...

Am I right here?

Comment: In .NET (and Windows) mutex and locks are note the same. Mutexes are used mostly for cross-process synchronization.

Comment: That code invites the client programmer to abuse the `using` statement.  Which resembles RAII, but it still has to be written explicitly.  It could have very easily been added to the C# language, like it was for `lock`, but the design team chose not to.  Code you can't see doing very untrivial things is not the C# way.  Imagine how many C++ programmers lost a week of their life trying to figure out why `}` crashed their program.  Notable is that the C++/CLI designers did in fact do just that, probably more to placate C++ programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for locking it's important that every lock that is acquired is also released (no matter if the code it was locking had any exceptions). So normally, no matter what lock you use, it'll look something like this:

```
myLock.MyAcquireMethod();
try
{
    //...
}
finally
{
    myLock.MyReleaseMethod();
}
```

Now for the `Monitor` locking mechanism in `c#` they have a keyword to make it easier: `lock`.

which basically wraps the acquiring and releasing in one `lock` code-block.

So this:

```
lock(myObj)
{
    //...
}
```

Is just a more convenient way of writing this:

```
Monitor.Enter(myObj);
try
{
    //...
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(myObj);
}
```

Sadly for the other locks (and because `Monitor` has it's limitations we don't always want to use it) we don't have such a handy short way of doing the whole thing, and to solve that the `ReaderWriterLockSlim_ScopedLockRead` wrapper implements `IDisposable` that gives you this `try` `finally` mechanism (`using` also guarantees that `Dispose()` is called on the `IDisposable` no matter if the code ran to completion or an exception occurred.

So instead of:

```
m_myLock.EnterWriteLock();
try
{
    //...
}
finally
{
    m_myLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

You're now able to do this:

```
using(new ReaderWriterLockSlim_ScopedLockRead(m_myLock))
{
    //...
}
```

Hope this answers your question!

As a bonus a warning on the `Monitor` class of `c#`. This locking mechanism is re-entrant on a thread level. Meaning the thread holding the lock is allowed to acquire it multiple times (though it also has to release it multiple times), which allows you to do something like this:

```
private readonly object _myLock = new object();

public void MyLockedMethod1()
{
    lock(_myLock)
    {
        MyLockedMethod2();
    }
}

public void MyLockedMethod2()
{
    lock(_myLock)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

So no matter if `MyLockedMethod2` is called directly or through `MyLockedMethod1` (that might need the lock for other stuff as well) you can have thread-safety.

However these days a lot of people use `async`/`await` where a method can be continued on a different thread, which can break the `Monitor` if the thread that acquired it is not the thread releasing it, so I advise you not to use something like this:

```
public async Task MyLockedMethod()
{
    lock(_myLock)
    {
        await MyAsyncMethod();
    }
}
```

Anyway there is a lot of documentation about this if you would like to learn more.

Comment: So, can I conclude that this method `lock(obj){}` and this `using(new ReaderWriterLockSlim_ScopedLockRead(m_myLock)){}` actually do the same, just second one is more suitable in some cases, right?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoschenko yes functionality wise it all boils down to the same pattern, though the `using` might not communicate exactly what us happening to someone reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not it at all. The Read Writer lock is an implementation used in a specific context.

- All can read at any time without one blocking the other, but blocking anyone who wants to write.
- None can read or write when there is even one writing at that time

It is exactly as [wikipedia describes it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) and non-specific for C# or any other language. This is just the C# flavor of a ReadWriter lock

> is a synchronization primitive that solves one of the readers–writers problems. An RW lock allows concurrent access for read-only operations, while write operations require exclusive access.

Check [Microsoft docs here for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?view=netframework-4.8)